Problem installing GEOS in Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to install GEOS in Ubuntu 22.04. According to their own installation instructions, I ran the following:
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get install geos

The final result is E: Unable to locate package geos.
I will say--I think I understand that I could install individual/component packages libgeos++-dev, libgeos-c1v5, etc. (see https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages), but I'm still kind of wondering why the installation of geos as such isn't working and/or if there's a way to get it working in that form.
Below is the output I got from running the individual commands.
(1) sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.99.22.9).
software-properties-common set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

(2) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
PPA publishes dbgsym, you may need to include 'main/debug' component
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Official stable UbuntuGIS packages.


More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa.gpg with fingerprint 2EC86B48E6A9F326623CD22FFF0E7BBEC491C6A1
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]     
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]      
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Sources [358 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,988 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Sources [208 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [627 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [690 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [901 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [731 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,123 kB]
Get:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [24.6 kB]
Get:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [176 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [261 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [26.1 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [19.2 kB]
Get:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [55.3 kB]
Get:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [25.0 kB]
Fetched 7,483 kB in 5s (1,412 kB/s)                                 
Reading package lists... Done

(3) sudo apt-get install geos
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package geos


Hmmm. Run sudo apt update and then try sudo apt install geos again.

What does "get it working in that form" mean? What is your end goal? geos appears to be the name of the source package - there's a utility package geos-bin that provides a program /usr/bin/geosop but apart from that it appears to be a library package.

@user535733 The result is the same (E: Unable to locate package geos), thanks though.

@steeldriver I suppose for "get it working in that form" I meant getting the command sudo apt-get install geos (or with apt rather than apt-get, I'm not super conversant in the differences) to successfully install everything. As for end goal...I mean on one level, I do just want the packages installed, and I'll accomplish that in the way I know how if needed. On another level, my end goal is to understand why this error is happening. Even if I can't fix it, I just want to know what the snag is.
